# Rails : Filter a model by 2nd childs attribute

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, arel

I can't seem to figure this out. I can do it if it goes one level deep. (using something like `A.joins(:bs).where("bs.paid = TRUE")`)

But I have a model A which `has_many B`. `B has_one C`. Finally `C` has an attribute `paid`.

I want to get all `A`'s where `C.paid == true`.

I am looking for something like `A.joins({:b, :c}).where("c.paid == True")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
A.joins(:b, :c).where(:conditions => ["c.paid = ?", true])
```

Found here, take a look it might interest you:
"**11.2.2 Joining Multiple Associations**"
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: Got it. I was looking for 11.2.3

Answer (score 1):

```
paid_items = Array.new

A.bs.each do |b_item|
  paid_items << b_item if b_item.c.paid
end
```

Comment: Readability is very important to me.  `A.bs` and `b_item.c` are using `ActiveRecord`.  This way it is more readable.

Comment: I am currently using solution exactly similar to yours. But I think using Arel this can be done easily.